# How to map object in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, object, input, mapping

I have mainPrice object:

```
client_type: "individual"
large_car: {100: "3", 200: "2.5"}
medium_car: {100: "3", 200: "2.5"}
small_car: {100: "2.5", 200: "2.5"}
x_large_car: {100: "3", 200: "2.5"}
xx_large_car: {100: "3", 200: "2.5"}
```

What I am trying to do is display each type of car inside of the input box. So basically I am trying to map it. So for example small_car:

```
<td>
            {Object.keys(mainPrice.small_car).map((key) => (
              <tr>
                <label>{key} miles: </label>
                <InputPrice
                  mainPricePosts={mainPrice.small_car[key]}
                  handleChange={handleChange}
                />
              </tr>
            ))}
          </td>
```

But I am getting an error **TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object** But I dont understand the reason of this error. Could you please have a look?

Edit: So lots of people says the issue is not about the map, that's why I want to explain more about the code. So on my parent component I make the API call to fetch the data and I setMainPrice with this data.  At the end, it is this object:

```
client_type: "individual"
    large_car: {100: "3", 200: "2.5"}
    medium_car: {100: "3", 200: "2.5"}
    small_car: {100: "2.5", 200: "2.5"}
    x_large_car: {100: "3", 200: "2.5"}
    xx_large_car: {100: "3", 200: "2.5"}
```

So, I send this data as a props to the current component where I try to display this data into textbox.

So here is the component:

```
const PricePostsIndividual = ({ mainPrice }) => {
  console.log({ mainPrice })
  return (
    <>
        <tbody className="price_coefficient">
          <td>
            {/* {Object.keys(mainPrice.small_car).map((key) => (
              <tr>
                <label>{key} miles: </label>
                <InputPrice
                  mainPricePosts={mainPrice.small_car[key]}
                  handleChange={handleChange}
                />
              </tr>
            ))} */}
          </td>
          
        </tbody>
    </>
  );
};

export default PricePostsIndividual;
```

As you see I commented isnide of   and mainProce is coming right in this case.

And the parent component:

```
export default function PriceCoefficient() {
  const [mainPrice, setMainPrice] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const res = await Axios({
          method: "POST",
          url: `url`,
          headers: {
            "cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          },
        });
        if (res.status === 200) {
          setMainPrice(res.data.main_price);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <PanelHeader size="sm" />
      <div className="content">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <Card>
              <CardBody>
                <h4>Main Prices</h4>
                <Table responsive>
                  <thead className="text-primary">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Small Cars</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <PricePostsMainPrice
                    mainPrice={mainPrice}
                    loading={loading}
                    error={error}
                  />
                </Table>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: assuming that you use snake_case all over the place, is the `mainPrice` like this or should be `main_price`?

Comment: Try this --> `Object.keys(mainPrice?.small_car || {})`

Comment: Maybe mainPrice is not having complete data at the time this function is called. Check that using console.log, and add more code if you still need help.

Comment: I see no over issues ***with this code*** be perhaps the issue is elsewhere and manifesting here. Please try to update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Prusdrum maiinPrice is the object that I gave in the question. I fulfill via fetching the data.

Comment: @Sarun UK it didnt help.. The problem is mainPrice is not null actually.

Comment: Ok let me check and bootstrap you code.

Comment: Is any part of what you are trying to render here fetched and loaded/saved into state asynchronously?

Comment: @Drew Reese I also added parent component in case I am missing something

Comment: I see, so `mainPrice` exists on the initial mount, but `mainPrice.small_car[key]` will throw because `small_car` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that your initial `mainPrice` state is an empty object (`{}`).

```
const [mainPrice, setMainPrice] = useState({});
```

This is passed, eventually it seems, on to `PricePostsIndividual` where it when you try `Object.keys(mainPrice.small_car)` the `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error is thrown.

```js
const mainPrice = {};

try {
  Object.keys(mainPrice.small_car);
  console.log('no error thrown');
} catch(error) {
  console.error(error.message);
}
```

## Solution

Use some null-checks (guard clauses) or Optional-Chaining, or provide a fallback value (Nullish Coalescing) for the nested state for mapping to JSX.

```js
const mainPrice = {};

try {
  // Null check/guard clause
  mainPrice.small_car && Object.keys(mainPrice.small_car);
  
  // Nullish Coalescing to provide fallback
  Object.keys(mainPrice.small_car ?? {});
  
  console.log('no error thrown');
} catch(error) {
  console.error(error.message);
}
```

I suggest the following:

```
const PricePostsIndividual = ({ mainPrice = {} }) => { // provide initial value
  return (
    <>
      <tbody className="price_coefficient">
        <td>
          // Use Object.entries to get array of key-value pairs
          // provide fallback for mainPrice.small_car
          {Object.entries(mainPrice.small_car ?? {}).map(([key, value]) => (
            <tr>
              <label>{key} miles: </label>  // render key
              <InputPrice
                mainPricePosts={value}      // render value
                handleChange={handleChange} // ensure this handler is defined!!
              />
            </tr>
          ))}
        </td>
      </tbody>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is the object, maybe the error refers to another problem.

```js
let object = {
  client_type: "individual",
  large_car: { 100: "3", 200: "2.5" },
  medium_car: { 100: "3", 200: "2.5" },
  small_car: { 100: "2.5", 200: "2.5" },
  x_large_car: { 100: "3", 200: "2.5" },
  xx_large_car: { 100: "3", 200: "2.5" }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(object.small_car).map((key) => (
          <tr>
            <label>{key} miles: </label>
            <input value={object.small_car[key]} />
          </tr>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: This is a comment since it doesn't resolve OP's issue.

Comment: It doesn't fix it because the error is not in that piece of code, in fact I indicated in the answer that the error is elsewhere.
Anyway ok, no problem :)

Comment: I edited the question :) maybe this time it is more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
            parts.map((part, partIndex) => {
              <tr>
                <label>{key} miles: </label>
                <InputPrice
                  mainPricePosts={part.small_car}
                  handleChange={handleChange}
                />
              </tr>
            ))}
          </td>
```

Comment: I hope this code will help you out from the situation.

Comment: But isnt it for mapping the array? I have an object actually

Comment: dear do have the multiple object inside the array or just one single object ?

Comment: Becuase map is for the array of object ,int , string it should be list not single object.

Comment: <div>
        
          <tr>
            <label>{key} miles: </label>
            <input value={object.small_car} />
          </tr>
       
      </div>

Comment: This is for the single object don't use the map just access you object after dot , consider him as normal object which you're access look like in the server side language.

Comment: So, mainPrice is a object that I indicated in the question. But the code you wrote isnt it for array. And I tried it actually, but it didnt help also.

Comment: No issue for object handle is very simple just the value after the dot it will appear for like e.g. mainPrice.small_car or mainPrice.large_car the value map automatic for you.

Comment: Yeah but I think the problem might be somewhere else, I updated the question. Could you have a look?

Comment: Kindly replace the variable name 100 to another like test_100 & this variable, i hope it will solve your problem, it happening because of the incorrect variable name.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jtrcmf?file=index.tsx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234561/discussion-between-shahzad-khan-and-magic-bean).

Comment: Thanks I could solve the issue, but really helpfull you were

Answer (score -2):

```
<td>
        {Object.keys(mainPrice.small_car).forEach((item) => (
          <tr>
            <label>{item} miles: </label>
            <InputPrice
              mainPricePosts={item}
              handleChange={handleChange}
            />
          </tr>
        ))}
      </td>
```

You should not use map here as you don't need to create another object . you just need to iterate.So, better to use foreach.

check item object and see what you need.

Comment: forEach does not return results so it would treat it as a collection of undefined`s

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` is a void return, this will fail miserably in React.